# Is it possible to work with a NX-APP with its own node_modules folder inside it while solving problems of incompatibility with monorepo of a package?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

Thanks to all the developers who create tools for developers working with Monorepos, such is the case of the Nx team; Many of us have been interested in moving our projects to Mono Repositories.

It is normal to find some difficulties during the conversion process; for example, some dependencies of your project are not developed to work in a multi-project workspace; for example, I was transforming a multi-repo project that I have, and I ran into this error:

`Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../capacitor.config.json'`

For that reason, I had to stop my migration temporarily, but the project must continue, hence my question.

**Is it possible to temporarily work with that project with its own node_modules folder inside, which fixes that problem?**

More than a yes or no answer, **is there a methodology to follow in such a situation?**